# I can't figure out php syntax

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have taxonomies that i need called here,

```
if ( $the_tax->name == 'day' , 'drink_type') {
        $tax_output = '';
    }
    return $tax_output;
}
```

The above code is written wrong, The taxonomy of  day works, i can not figure out how to ref a second taxonomy of drink_type.
do i use a comma? or || or what () if anyone knows php syntax and can help THANKS!

Comment: It is two pipes `||` between your two conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need logical `OR` (which can be written as `||` (common syntax) or just `OR` (which is PHP specific so I rather do not recommend using) - [see logical operators doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for more details. So your code should look like this:

```
if( ($the_tax->name == 'day') || ($the_tax->name == 'drink_type') ) {
   // at least one condition met
}
```

or use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) if you going to have more allowed names:

```
$names = ['day','drink_type'];
if( in_array($the_tax->name, $names) {
  // allowed name...
}
```

Comment: I have NO php logic, lol. This makes so much sense now that i see it done correctly. you da man marcin

Answer (score 1):

Separate the conditions with `||` (logical OR)

```
if ( $the_tax->name == 'day' ||  $the_tax->name == 'drink_type') {
        $tax_output = '';
}
return $tax_output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you said, the correct syntax would be :

```
if ( $the_tax->name == 'day' || $the_tax->name == 'drink_type') { 
// Note that you can't use id ($var == 'X' || 'Y')
```

Comment: More likely the function's end ;-)

Comment: @NicoKaag Hum yeah ! :p Deleted this part anyway, not usefull for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax uses two pipes in between your two conditions of the if statement. Like this,

```
$tax_output;

if ( $the_tax->name == 'day' || $the_tax->name == 'drink_type') {
    $tax_output = '';
}
return $tax_output;
```

I left out your ending`}` because as is it will throw a syntax error. If that ending bracket is supposed to be there then you should add the part of the code that contains the opening bracket as well.

Comment: function gmw_remove_taxonomies_from_results( $tax_output, $gmw,         $post, $the_tax ) {
        
        if ($the_tax->name == 'day' || $the_tax->name == 'drink_type') {
            $tax_output = '';
        }
        return $tax_output;
    }
    add_filter( 'gmw_pt_results_taxonomy', 'gmw_remove_taxonomies_from_results', 10, 4 );